# UseDispatch() dentro de um useEffect() -> *missing dependency*

Tags: javascript, react, redux, react-hooks

ALERTA: **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatcher'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import ACTION from './Action'

const App = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const REDUCER_USUARIOS = useSelector(state => state.ReducerUsuarios)
  
  //Estou usando como componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {  
   dispatch(ACTION.CARREGAR())
  }, [])
  
  console.log(REDUCER_USUARIOS)
  
  return <div>TEST</div>

}
```

OBS: Estou usando React(version:16.12) e React-Redux(version:7.1.3) com Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

O alerta é dado pois a função dispatch não está no array de dependência do useEffect.
Para solucionar precisa deixar desta forma

```
 useEffect(() => {  
    dispatch(ACTION.CARREGAR())
 }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: Valeu Vicenzo! era isso mesmo.